# Are the dates and places you see when freeze framing actually easter eggs referencing DC lore?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In *Legends of Tomorrow - 1x10 - Progeny* just after the team arrives in the future, we get a prompt on screen of when and where we are for this episode.

In normal viewing speed, it appears to be gibberish until it settles on the correct place and time.

When viewed frame-by-frame, however, it looks like this:

- [image] (= their starting point from the previous episode),
- [image],
- [image],
- [image],
- [image],
- [image],
- [image],
- [image], before finally settling on
- [image] (= their destination).

So the obvious question is, **do these dates and places have any significance?**

***PS:*** As this is an Easter Egg, I'm including the [dc-comics](/questions/tagged/dc-comics) tag, since it probably hints to something in comic lore.

**Edit:**

Turns out they did this throughout the season whenever the effect appeared (which might help answer whether it is just random [plus I was curious, so I went through them all and this might actually be of interest to some]).

**Edit 2:** September 2017 - added *Legends* Season 2 and *The Flash* episode 3x22.

```
Episode     Number of   Place                   Year            Event / Scene / 
Number      Appearance                                          Context **SPOILERS**
            of effect
            in the
            episode
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
1x01        1           Amsterdam               2016            Attack on London
                        Moscow                  2025
                        Cape Town               2050
                        Tokyo                   2073
                        Star City               2094
                        New York                2127
                        Central City            2142
                        New York                2150
                        London                  2166

            2           Mumbai                  2016            Picking up Sara Lance
                        Venice                  2016
                        Seattle                 2016
                        Hub City                2016
                        Madrid                  2016
                        Los Angeles             2016
                        River City              2016
                        Geneva                  2016
                        Tibet                   2016

            3           San Diego               2016            Picking up Firestorm
                        Vestal                  2016
                        Bagdad                  2016
                        Coast City              2016
                        Seoul                   2016
                        Boston                  2016
                        Opal City               2016
                        Bangkok                 2016
                        Pittsburgh              2016

            4           Calcutta                2016            Picking up the Hawks
                        Midway City             2016
                        Williamston             2016
                        Denver                  2016
                        Karachi                 2016
                        Starfish Island         2016
                        Houston                 2016
                        Cincinnati              2016
                        St. Roch                2016

            5           Helsinki                2016            Picking up the Rogues
                        Melbourne               2016
                        Dakota City             2016
                        Tulsa                   2016
                        Florence                2016
                        New Orleans             2016
                        Chicago                 2016
                        Happy Harbour           2016
                        Central City            2016

            6           Manila                  2016            Visiting Aldus
                        Krakow                  2009
                        National City           2002
                        Tehran                  1997
                        San Francisco           1993
                        Acapulco                1988
                        Bludhaven               1983
                        Peach Tree City         1981
                        St Roch                 1975

            7           Markovia                1975            I got a Nuke
                        Geneva                  1975
                        Vienna                  1975
                        Detroit                 1975
                        Keystone City           1975
                        Belfast                 1975
                        Cairo                   1975
                        Chattanooga             1975
                        Norway                  1975

1x02        1           Hong Kong               1975            Welcome to TerrorCon '75
                        Rome                    1975
                        Port Washington         1975
                        Baton Rouge             1975
                        Nanda Parbat            1975
                        Portland                1975
                        Civic City              1975
                        Central City            1975
                        Norway                  1975

            2           Kansas City             1975            Visiting young Martin
                        Rome                    1975
                        Budapest                1975
                        Nairobi                 1975
                        Steel City              1975
                        Philadelphia            1975
                        Gateway City            1975
                        Algiers                 1975
                        Ivy Town                1975

1x03        1           San Francisco           1700 BC         Backstab Interruptus
                        Austin                  1700 BC
                        Geneva                  1700 BC
                        Tulsa                   1700 BC
                        Paris                   1700 BC
                        Metropolis              1700 BC
                        New York                1700 BC
                        Haddonfield             1700 BC
                        Ancient Egypt           1700 BC

            2           Portland                1975            Going to the Bank
                        Boston                  1975
                        Seoul                   1975
                        Jakarta                 1975
                        River City              1975
                        Detroit                 1975
                        Burbank                 1975
                        Steel City              1975
                        Leipzig                 1975

            3           Philadelphia            1975            Visiting Little Leonard
                        Cleveland               1975
                        Tokyo                   1975
                        Seattle                 1975
                        Crystal Lake            1975
                        Arkham City             1975
                        Chicago                 1975
                        Manila                  1975
                        Central City            1975

1x04        1           Chattanooga             1975            Raiders of the Pentagon Archives
                        Madrid                  1979
                        Star City               1980
                        Lisbon                  1981
                        Metropolis              1982
                        Coast City              1983
                        Atlanta                 1984
                        Gotham City             1985
                        Washington, D.C.        1986

            2           Atlanta                 1986            Crash Landing
                        Stockholm               1986
                        Vancouver               1986
                        Central City            1986
                        Madrid                  1986
                        New York City           1986
                        Star City               1986
                        Bern                    1986
                        Soviet Union            1986

1x05        1           Boston                  1986            Crash Site
                        Brussels                1986
                        Star City               1986
                        Chicago                 1986
                        Tokyo                   1986
                        Opal City               1986
                        Philadelphia            1986
                        San Francisco           1986
                        Soviet Union            1986

1x06        1           Moscow                  1988            Mick Rory's Paradise
                        London                  1989
                        Tokyo                   1996
                        Emerald City            1999
                        Manila                  2002
                        Norfolk                 2008
                        Trenton                 2011
                        Culver City             2023
                        Star City               2046

1x08        1           Heidelberg              2146            Hot Rod Racing
                        West Lafayette          2111
                        Manchester              2092
                        Nanda Parbat            2053
                        Edinburgh               2041
                        Markovia                2001
                        Peachtree City          1982
                        Winchester              1974
                        Harmony Falls           1958

1x09        1           Detroit                 1958            Aaaaand.... they're gone...
                        Amsterdam               1958
                        Tulsa                   1958
                        Star City               1958
                        Hong Kong               1958
                        Ivy Town                1958
                        Acapulco                1958
                        New Orleans             1958
                        Harmony Falls           1958

            2           Harmony Falls           1958            League Business a.k.a. My-Time-Drive-is-still-a-bit-wonky-and-all-over-the-place
                        Boston                  2011
                        Riverside               2055
                        Star City               2146
                        Perris                  1975
                        Moscow                  1975
                        Binghamton              1995
                        Steel City              1972
                        Nanda Parbat            1960

1x10        1           Nanda Parbat            1960            Kill or Capture?
                        Vestal                  1977
                        Cincinnati              1989
                        Civic City              1999
                        Geneva                  2022
                        Shanghai                2057
                        Venice                  2098
                        Gotham City             2112
                        Kasnia Conglomerate     2147

1x11        1           Kasnia Conglomerate     2147            Yeeha...
                        Helsinki                2133
                        Markovia                2058
                        Keystone City           2014
                        Cairo                   1991
                        Stafford                1962
                        Calvin City             1909
                        San Francisco           1899
                        Salvation               1871

            2           Salvation               1871            The House is on Fire...
                        Boston                  1899
                        Starfish Island         1909
                        Dallas                  1929
                        Manila                  1938
                        Portland                1943
                        Belfast                 1965
                        Cleveland               1982
                        Central City            1990

1x12        1           Salvation               1871            The House is (still) on Fire... (Recap) / Rescuing young Mick
                        Boston                  1899
                        Starfish Island         1909
                        Dallas                  1929
                        Manila                  1938
                        Portland                1943
                        Belfast                 1965
                        Cleveland               1982
                        Central City            1990

            2           Central City            1990            Rescuing young Sara
                        Chicago                 1992
                        Paradise Island         1995
                        Austin                  1998
                        Bangkok                 2000
                        Seattle                 2002
                        Hong Kong               2004
                        Memphis                 2006
                        Starling City           2007

            3           Starling City           2007            Rescuing slightly younger Ray
                        Denver                  1996
                        Acapulco                2001
                        Burbank                 1992
                        Algiers                 2011
                        Seoul                   2008
                        London                  2000
                        Athens                  2012
                        Star City               2014            [since the city was renamed in 2015 it should still be StarLING City in 2014 as well]

            4           Star City               2014            Rescuing Baby Leonard  ["Star City" is still incorrect]
                        Philadelphia            1989
                        Berlin                  1987
                        Minneapolis             1985
                        Boulder                 1982
                        Cairo                   1980
                        Opal City               1977
                        Tehran                  1974
                        Central City            1972

            5           Central City            1972            Rescuing Baby Martin
                        Pasadena                1970
                        Kyoto                   1967
                        Detroit                 1963
                        Keystone City           1960
                        Sydney                  1959
                        Bludhaven               1955
                        Buenos Aires            1952
                        Ivy Town                1950

            6           Ivy Town                1950            Rescuing Baby Jax
                        Coast City              1962
                        Melbourne               1967
                        Baghdad                 1970
                        Newark                  1979
                        Florence                1983
                        Toledo                  1988
                        Portsmouth              1990
                        Central City            1993

1x13        1           Tulsa                   1996            Destination: London
                        Bern                    2003
                        Gotham                  2013
                        Boston                  2034
                        Berlin                  2049
                        Seoul                   2062
                        Madrid                  2094
                        Minsk                   2125
                        London                  2166

            2           London                  2166            A-Maze-ing Training
                        Ottowa                  2113            [sic! apparently the Capital of Canada will get a vowel shift]
                        Star City               2092
                        Oklahoma City           2044
                        Bern                    2001
                        Metropolis              1989
                        West Hills              1978
                        Los Alamos              1958
                        Iowa City               1941

1x14        1           London                  2166 AD         Jail Rip
                        Central City            2016 AD
                        Geneva                  1776 AD
                        Sanam                   1423 AD
                        Paris                   1002 AD
                        Rome                     522 AD
                        Maya City                683 BC
                        Timbuktu                1120 BC
                        Ancient Egypt           1700 BC

1x15        1           Central City                            On the roof again
                        Philadelphia
                        Maui
                        Moscow
                        Gotham City
                        Baltimore
                        Rome
                        Portsmouth
                        Star City               5 months ago

            2           Star City               2166            Repairing the Jump Ship
                        Seattle                 2111
                        Amsterdam               2093
                        Atlanta                 2076
                        Metropolis              2055
                        Ivy Town                2043
                        Acapluco                2031
                        Nairobi                 2028
                        Central City            2016

            3           Central City            2016            Back to the Blitz
                        Los Angelas             2031
                        Bludhaven               2043
                        Chicago                 2066
                        Baghdad                 2088
                        Buenos Aires            2105
                        Midway City             2131
                        Florence                2145
                        London                  2166

1x16        1           THE VANISHING POINT     ...             Hey, it's May!
                        Berlin                  2213
                        Metropolis              2043
                        San Diego               1988
                        Morocco                 2105
                        Paris                   2309
                        New York City           1908
                        Madrid                  2145
                        Star City               2016

            2           Star City               2016            Mick's Heist
                        Vestal                  2016
                        Washington, D.C.        2016
                        San Francisco           2016
                        Buenos Aires            2016
                        Bern                    2016
                        Philadelphia            2016
                        Houston                 2016
                        Central City            2016

            3           Central City            2016            La Résistance
                        Memphis                 2009
                        Coast City              2001
                        Phoenix                 1989
                        Venice                  1978
                        Shreveport              1966
                        New Orleans             1957
                        Markovia                1950
                        Saint-Lô, France        1944

            4           Central City            2016            Vampire Vandal draws Blood
                        Charlotte               2007
                        Midway City             2003
                        Athens                  1992
                        Happy Harbour           1977
                        Portland                1963
                        Newark                  1953
                        Stockholm               1949
                        Saint-Lô, France        1944

            5           Central City            2016            Runter von der Strasse!
                        Memphis                 2009
                        Coast City              2001
                        Phoenix                 1989
                        Venice                  1978
                        Shreveport              1966
                        New Orleans             1957
                        Markovia                1950
                        Saint-Lô, France        1944

            6           Saint-Lô, France        1944            Nice meeting Me
                        Mumbai                  1946
                        River City              1947
                        Calcutta                1949
                        Tokyo                   1951
                        Denver                  1953
                        Helsinki                1954
                        Tehran                  1957
                        Harmony Falls           1958

            7           Harmony Falls           1958            Setting Up 2021 Bomb
                        Nairobi                 1966
                        Ivy Town                1977
                        Budapest                1989
                        Seattle                 1995
                        Pittsburgh              2000
                        Vienna                  2003
                        Kansas City             2015
                        St. Roch                2021

            8           St. Roch                2021            Setting Up 1958 Bomb
                        Atlanta                 2016
                        Civic City              2007
                        Rio de Janeiro          1998
                        Acapulco                1992
                        Boston                  1983
                        Steel City              1977
                        Portsmouth              1966
                        Harmony Falls           1958

            9           Harmony Falls           1958            Setting Up 1975 Bomb
                        Minneapolis             1960
                        Coral City              1963
                        Bangkok                 1966
                        Seoul                   1968
                        Sydney                  1969
                        Star City               1970
                        Alexandria              1971
                        Norway                  1975

            10          St. Roch                2021            For her...
                        Tulsa                   2050
                        Steel City              2119
                        Lincoln                 2018
                        Vatican City            1978
                        Cairo                   2013
                        Geneva                  2170
                        Kansas City             1871
                        Star City               2016

            11          Star City               2016            Strip Club
                        Krakow                  2188
                        Cuzco                   1941
                        Fairbanks               1883
                        Tehran                  1998
                        Johnson City            1977
                        Starfish Island         2199
                        Milan                   1965
                        Central City            2013

            12          Central City            2013            "Is this May 2016?" a.k.a. Man, what Hour is this?
                        San Antonio             2201
                        Baton Rouge             1911
                        Bludhaven               1986
                        Melbourne               2045
                        Maui                    1966
                        Opal City               2142
                        Rome                    1969
                        Star City               2016



2x01        1           Cairo                   1142            Nate goes to meet Oliver
                        Sioux City              1908
                        Rome                    1311
                        Coast City              1877
                        Algiers                 1669
                        River City              1772
                        Vienna                  1532
                        Helsinki                1499
                        Star City               2016

                        Atlantic Ocean    24 hours later

            2           Star City               2016            Saving the King of France / Making out with the Queen
                        San Francisco           1988
                        Moscow                  1969
                        Coast City              1872
                        Atlanta                 1779
                        Markovia                1661
                        Geneva                  1701
                        Tokyo                   1699
                        France                  1637

            3           France                  1637            Abducting Albert
                        Chicago                 1678
                        Vatican City            1701
                        Nanda Parbat            1724
                        Koshmar                 1745
                        Hub City                1803
                        Alcapulco               1855
                        Seoul                   1909
                        New York City           1942

            4           Star City               2016            Re-Collecting the Crew I: Ray
                        San Diego               1901
                        Baton Rouge             1778
                        Bludhaven               1486
                        Paris                   1208
                        Venice                   426
                        Opal City                233
                        Rome                     169
                        South Dakota    70 Million Years Ago

            5           South Dakota    70 Million Years Ago    Re-Collecting the Crew II: Firestorm
                        Mesopotamia             1962
                        Alexandria              1776
                        Sparta                  1467
                        Corinth                 1221
                        El Kef                   977
                        Arwad                    512
                        Babylon                  133
                        Tintangel, England       821

            5           Tintangel, England       821            Re-Collecting the Crew III: Sara
                        Troy                     742
                        Carthage                 952
                        Athens                  1004
                        Moscow                  1233
                        Tehran                  1386
                        River City              1557
                        Calcutta                1624
                        Salem                   1693

            6           Tintangel, England       821            Get the Einsteins!
                        Athens                   978
                        Madrid                  1273
                        Petra                   1377
                        Troy                    1463
                        Boston                  1772
                        Rapid City              1833
                        Central City            1899
                        Columbia University     1942

2x02        1           Arlington               1942            Captured by the JSA
                        Edge City               1942
                        Karachi                 1942
                        San Dimas               1942
                        Fabletown               1942
                        Bossier City            1942
                        JSA Headquarters        1942

            2 & 3       JSA Headquarters        1942            Eobard arrives in Nazi-occupied Paris -- and so do the Legends
                        Gateway City            1942
                        Santa Fe                1942
                        Guernica                1942
                        Dakota City             1942
                        Krakow                  1942
                        Binghamton              1942
                        Tokyo                   1942
                        Paris                   1942

            4           Paris                   1942            Killing SteroidNazi
                        Civic City              1942
                        Madrid                  1942
                        Rio                     1942
                        Denver                  1942
                        River City              1942
                        San Diego               1942
                        Seoul                   1942
                        Fontainebleau Forest    1942

            5           Fontainebleau Forest    1942            Taking the JSA home
                        Cincinnati              1942
                        Happy Harbor            1942
                        Belfast                 1942
                        Shanghai                1942
                        Dakota City             1942
                        Mumbai                  1942
                        Cuzco                   1942
                        New York City           1942

2x03        1           New York City           1942            Don't Fight in the Cargo Bay!
                        Whitchata               1902
                        Hub City                1859
                        Sao Paulo               1823
                        Venice                  1812
                        Keystone City           1799
                        Athens                  1747
                        Maui                    1688
                        Kansai Region, Japan    1641

2x04        1           Kansai Region, Japan    1641            Zo-.. Zo-.. Zom-.. Stein can't say it...
                        Midway City             1673
                        Madrid                  1682
                        San Francisco           1721
                        Houston                 1772
                        Calvin City             1801
                        Budapest                1847
                        Cairo                   1851
                        Mississippi             1863

2x05        1           Mississippi             1863            DaMiami Vice
                        Star City               1874
                        Algiers                 1892
                        San Jose                1911
                        Baton Rouge             1934
                        Hub City                1944
                        Geneva                  1956
                        Maui                    1975
                        Miami                   1987

            2           Miami                   1987            Tourists in the White House!
                        Bludhaven               1987
                        Rome                    1987
                        Belfast                 1987
                        Karachi                 1987
                        National City           1987            [\S/]
                        Seoul                   1987
                        Seattle                 1987
                        Washington, D.C.        1987

2x06        1           Washington, D.C.        1987            Shooting the Time Pirate / Hanging Hex
                        Hub City                1965
                        Paris                   1942
                        Brussels                1923
                        Santa Fe                1901
                        Star City               1894
                        Portland                1889
                        Newark                  1881
                        Liberty, Colorado       1874

2x07        1           Liberty, Colorado       1874            Hangar/Hall (of Justice) Thing
                        Calvin City             1889
                        Madrid                  1902
                        Bangkok                 1929
                        Santa Barbara           1941
                        Bludhaven               1984
                        Atlanta                 1999
                        Moscow                  2011
                        Central City            2016

            2           Central City            2016            Reverse Alien Abduction Attempt
                        Midway City             2008
                        London                  1997
                        Rapid City              1989
                        Baton Rouge             1974
                        Helsinki                1969
                        Houston                 1962
                        Vestal                  1957
                        Redmond, Oregon         1951

            3           Coast City              1955            Back to Invasion
                        Tokyo                   1959
                        Rome                    1963
                        Calvin City             1967
                        Shanghai                1979
                        Tulsa                   1984
                        Denver                  1996
                        Manila                  2003
                        Central City            2016

2x08        1           Central City            2016            Al meets Legion
                        Salt Lake City          2009
                        Acapulco                1994
                        Rapid City              1988
                        Cuzco                   1972
                        San Dimas               1965
                        Krakow                  1956
                        Keystone City           1942
                        Chicago                 1927

            2           Chicago                 1927            Hollywood Hunter
                        Cairo                   1929
                        Nairobi                 1935
                        Opal City               1938
                        Atlanta                 1943
                        Manila                  1948
                        Starfish Island         1952
                        Erie                    1961
                        Los Angeles             1967

2x09                    New York            6 months ago

            1           Chicago                 1927            The Sixties!
                        Brussels                1933
                        Bangkok                 1934
                        Central City            1939
                        Seattle                 1942
                        Athens                  1947
                        Fabletown               1954
                        Tulsa                   1963
                        Los Angeles             1967

2x10                    Star City           8 months ago        Collecting Malcolm

                                            Present Day

            1           Los Angeles             1967            Meeting Lily at Jitters
                        Amsterdam               1972
                        Johnson City            1977
                        Gateway City            1984
                        Cincinnati              1989
                        Calcutta                1995
                        Happy Harbor            2004
                        Newark                  2011
                        Central City            2017

            2 & 3       Central City            2016            Taking it to the Bank
                        Manila                  2018
                        Hub City                2019
                        Tehran                  2019
                        Buenos Aires            2020
                        Atlanta                 2021
                        River City              2022
                        Guernica                2024
                        Zurich                  2025

            4           Zurich                  2025            There Goes the 1$ bill ...      
                        Dakota City             2001
                        Minneapolis             1982
                        Tokyo                   1963
                        Phoenix                 1915
                        Vienna                  1877
                        New Carthage            1832
                        Cairo                   1793
                        New Jersey              1776
                                            Christmas Day

2x11        1           Zurich                  2025            There Goes the 1$ bill ...      
                        Dakota City             2001
                        Minneapolis             1982
                        Tokyo                   1963
                        Phoenix                 1915
                        Vienna                  1877
                        New Carthage            1832
                        Cairo                   1793
                        New Jersey              1776
                                            Christmas Day

            2           New Jersey              1776            Rescue George W.!
                        Coast City              1776
                        Florence                1776
                        Moscow                  1776
                        Boston                  1776
                        Paris                   1776
                        Bludhaven               1776
                        Rome                    1776
                        Pennsylvania            1776
                                            Christmas Eve

2x12        1           Pennsylvania            1776            We're off to see the Wizard! (Well, she's a Witch)
                        Keystone City           1865
                        Miami                   1990
                        Calcutta                2116
                        Belfast                 2399
                        Tokyo                   2543
                        Calvin City             2755
                        Seoul                   2838
                        Detroit                 3000

2x13        1           Camelot                  507            Preparing for Launch (next episode)
                        Rome                     879
                        London                  1123
                        Florence                1322
                        Vatican City            1476
                        Boston                  1663
                        Central City            1782
                        Atlanta                 1896
                        NASA Flight Operations  1970

2x14        1           Camelot                  507            Dropping off Grandpa
                        Rome                     998
                        Fabletown               1103
                        Baghdad                 1377
                        Boston                  1632
                        Melbourne               1842
                        Steel City              1899
                        London                  1921
                        Manhattan               1965
                        NASA's Manned Spacecraft Center
                                April 13, 1970

2x15        1           Houston                 1970            Into the Trenches
                        Midway City             1965            
                        Boston                  1961
                        Madrid                  1952
                        San Francisco           1948
                        Hong Kong               1937
                        Rapid City              1932
                        Sao Paulo               1924
                        France                  1916
                                    72 Hours Earlier

2x16        1           France                  1916            Smoak Gunned Down (well more like Break a Neck...)
                        Los Angeles             1923
                        Belfast                 1945
                        Vienna                  1957
                        Maui                    1969
                        Vestal                  1977
                        Coast City              1999
                        Budapest                2004
                        Star City               2017

            2           Star City               2017            Malcolm comes for a chat
                        Shanghai                2017
                        Moscow                  2017
                        San Diego               2017
                        Denver                  2017
                        Bludhaven               2017
                        Chicago                 2017
                        Sydney                  2017
                        Central City            2017

            3           Central City            2017            Ray the Janitor's flat
                        Tulsa                   2017
                        Seoul                   2017
                        Pittsburgh              2017
                        Florence                2017
                        Midway City             2017
                        New Orleans             2017
                        Hong Kong               2017
                        Star City               2017

2x17        1           Star City               2017            Back to the Trenches
                        Chicago                 2009
                        Melbourne               2001
                        Atlanta                 1988
                        Bludhaven               1962
                        Florence                1957
                        Calvin City             1945
                        Calcutta                1923
                        France                  1916

            2           France                  1916            Dropping off Snart
                        Pittsburgh              1929
                        Seattle                 1936
                        Bangkok                 1949
                        Cairo                   1953
                        Kansas City             1976
                        Happy Harbor            1999
                        Acapulco                2008
                        Central City            2014

            3           Central City            2014            Dropping off Dark
                        Alexandria              2011
                        Los Angeles             2008
                        Sydney                  2003
                        Civic City              1998
                        Moscow                  1995
                        Rome                    1992
                        Steel City              1990
                        Miami                   1987


Flash 3x22  1           Central City            2017            Fetching Snart from Season 1
                        Venice                  2003
                        Happy Harbor            1989
                        Johnson City            1977
                        Madrid                  1959
                        Fabletown               1934
                        Paris                   1923
                        Los Angeles             1910
                        Siberia                 1892
```

Comment: Cool. While you're at it, I am curious if Blüdhaven is indeed lacking the umlauts in all it's listings.

Comment: @Thunderforge It usually is rather difficult to see if the umlauts are there, due to a lack in contrast with the background, but are very obviously missing in 1x15, where they should be easily visible in the smoke cloud rising from Westminster Abbey...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification with Vestak. Although that leads to the question of why Vestal appears 3 times, yet appears to be a small US town. Is it a reference to something I don't know about?

Comment: @Thunderforge I thought about it being the birthplace from somebody in the production staff or something like that.... Greg Berlanti is from Rye, NY; Marc Guggenheim from Long Island, NY ... which are both quite a bit away from Vestal; Wikipedia articles about Andy Kreisberg and Phil Klemmer (the other two execs) don't mention their birth places...

Comment: No luck with birthplaces for the Season 1 cast members either. Although I was surprised to learn that four of them are British (Arthur Darvill I figured, but there's also Dominic Purcell, Wentworth Miller, and Franz Drameh). I suppose if these small towns are someone's birthplaces, it could very well be those of the people who did the work to insert the easter eggs.

Comment: @Thunderforge Well, since you asked.... :D  Have fun... Included the Flash episode with Snart that has the effect, couldn't find any in the crossover epsiodes (except the Legends one of course) - presumably because there was no time travel .. just "normal" On Screen Display of city names such as "Star City" and "National City" without the year.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are quite a few easter eggs in the city names, but I wasn't able to spot any easter eggs with the city-year pairing.

## Easter Eggs

Note that pretty much any fictional city that exists in DC Comics has been referenced in passing throughout the Arrowverse shows. For instance, Caitlin Snow once says offhand that Ronnie Raymond lived in Midway City. For these cities, I've included the most relevant reference to each city in relation to the Arrowverse.

### Episode 1x01

#### Time Jump 1

- [Star City](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Star_City): The home city of Oliver Queen/Green Arrow and the setting for the Arrowverse show *Arrow*. The Legends eventually go to the city in 2046.
- [Central City](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Central_City_(Earth_One)): The home city of Barry Allen/The Flash and the setting for the Arrowverse show *The Flash*.

#### Time Jump 2

- [Hub City](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Hub_City): Roy Harper went to hide out here after he retired from being Arsenal and Tobias Church started his crime spree here (*Arrow*). Also, Roy Palmer and Kendra Saunders eventually settle in this city when they are trapped in 1956. In DC Comics, it is the home of Vic Sage, the first [Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_(comics)), and Dan Garret, the first [Blue Beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Beetle). Both of these characters were created by Charlton Comics, which was bought by DC Comics in 1983.
- River City: In DC Comics, the home of [Odd Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_Man_(comics)). Also the fictional town where the Broadway musical *[The Music Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Music_Man)* is set.

#### Time Jump 3

- [Coast City](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Coast_City): Before the events of *Legends*, Cisco gathered Flash, Atom, Firestorm, and Vixen (Mari McCabe) to stop Weather Wizard from destroying this city (*Vixen* Season 2). In DC Comics, it's the home of [Hal Jordan/Green Lantern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hal_Jordan).
- [Opal City](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Opal_City): Jesse Quick boarded a bus to there in *The Flash* Season 2. In DC Comics, it's the home of [Starman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starman_(comics)).

#### Time Jump 4

- [Midway City](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Midway_City): Patty Spivot went to study at Midway City University in *The Flash* Season 2. In DC Comics, it's the home of the [Doom Patrol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_Patrol) and the base of operations for Hawkman and Hawkgirl. This is appropriate since the goal of this time jump is to pick up the Hawks.
- [Starfish Island](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Starfish_Island): In DC Comics, the name of the island where Oliver Queen was shipwrecked and became the Green Arrow. On *Arrow*, this same island is named Lian Yu.
- [St. Roch](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/St._Roch): In DC Comics, it's "The City the Saints Forgot" and for a time is the base of operations for the Hawks in the early 2000s. This is where they are picked up in the show. The team will return to it shortly in 1975 to visit Aldus.

#### Time Jump 5

- [Dakota City](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Dakota_City): The primary setting of the [Dakotaverse](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Dakotaverse), published by Milestone Comics, which was later bought by DC Comics. It was integrated into the main DC Universe as part of the New 52. Several superheroes live here, notably [Static](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_(DC_Comics)), star of the animated TV show *[Static Shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_Shock)*.
- [Happy Harbor](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Happy_Harbor): In DC Comics, the original Secret Sanctuary location for the Justice League of America.

#### Time Jump 6

- [National City](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/National_City): The home of Kara Danvers/Supergirl. Note that at this point, *Supergirl* was on the air, but was not officially part of the Arrowverse.
- [Blüdhaven](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Bl%C3%BCdhaven): A location near Star City where Malcolm Merlyn and Deadshot have hidden (*Arrow*). In DC Comics, the home of [Dick Grayson/Nightwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightwing) (formerly Robin).

#### Time Jump 7

- [Markovia](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Markovia): A fictional East European country where Diggle and the rest of the Suicide Squad went on their first formal mission (*Arrow* "[Suicide Squad](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Suicide_Squad)"). In DC Comics, home to [Brion Markov/Geo-Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-Force).
- [Detroit](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Detroit): A real-world city that is the home of Mari McCabe/Vixen (not to be confused with Amaya Jiwe/Vixen, who joined the Legends in Season 2) and the primary setting for the animated Arrowverse show *Vixen*.
- [Keystone City](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Keystone_City): The location of Iron Heights Prison, where Barry Allen's father was held and metahuman criminals are locked up (*The Flash*). In DC Comics, it's home to the Golden Age [Jay Garrick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(Jay_Garrick)) and later [Wally West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wally_West) when he no longer was Kid Flash and became The Flash.

### Episode 1x02

#### Time Jump 1

- [Hong Kong](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Hong_Kong): Where Oliver Queen spent his third year in exile under the supervision of Amanda Waller. In DC Comics, several supers have operated there, notably [Cassandra Cain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra_Cain), who has been both Batgirl and Orphan.
- [Nanda Parbat](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Nanda_Parbat_(location)): The hidden city of the League of Assassins. The Legends visit there later in the season to retrieve Sara.
- [Civic City](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Civic_City): In DC Comics, a former home for the Justice Society of America.

#### Time Jump 2

- [Steel City](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Steel_City): In the *[Teen Titans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Titans_(TV_series))* animated TV series, the home of the [Titans East](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Titans_East_(Teen_Titans_TV_Series)), a group of superhero allies to the Teen Titans.
- [Gateway City](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Gateway_City): In DC Comics, it has been the home to [Jim Corrigan/Spectre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(comics)) (who would later appear in Season 2 of *Legends*) and [Princess Diana of Themyscira/Wonder Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman).
- [Ivy Town](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Ivy_Town): The Legends are here to see a young Martin Stein, and we find out in 1x12 that he was born here. In DC comics, it is the home of Ray Palmer (the second person to be the Atom) and his successor [Ryan Choi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(Ryan_Choi)) (the fourth person to be the Atom).

### Episode 1x03

#### Time Jump 1

*Note that these locations all have the year 1700 BC, so all of them except "Ancient Egypt" obviously do not exist yet.*

- [Metropolis](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Metropolis): Home of Clark Kent/Superman. Note that at this point, *Supergirl* was on the air, but was not officially part of the Arrowverse, and Superman had not yet been fully shown.
- Haddonfield: The fictional Illinois town of the *[Halloween](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_(franchise))* horror film franchise.

#### Time Jump 2

*By this point we start seeing repeats, like River City and Steel City.*

#### Time Jump 3

- Crystal Lake: Camp Crystal Lake is the fictional setting for the *[Friday the 13th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th_%28franchise%29)* horror film franchise.
- [Arkham City](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Arkham_City): In the video game *[Batman: Arkham City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Arkham_City)*, it is a super-prison enclosing the slums of what was formerly known as Gotham North. It eventually made its way into DC Comics as well.

### Episode 1x04

#### Time Jump 1

- [Atlanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlanta): A real-world city that is home to John Constantine in the Arrowverse show *Constantine*. (While not directly stated, his phone number has an Atlanta area code and the show was filmed there).
- [Gotham City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotham_City): In DC Comics, the home of [Bruce Wayne/Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman). Episode 1x13 calls it "Gotham" while Episode 1x15 reverts to "Gotham City".

### Episode 1x06

#### Time Jump 1

- [Emerald City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerald_City): The capital city in the children's novel *[The Wonderful Wizard of Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Wizard_of_Oz)*. A different city with the same name has [appeared](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Emerald_City) in DC Comics, although I can't find much information about it.

### Episode 1x08

#### Time Jump 1

- Manchester: In DC Comics, [Manchester, Alabama](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Manchester,_Alabama) is the adopted home of several speedsters, including Bart Allen (at the time known as "Impluse", later "Kid Flash).

### Episode 1x11

#### Time Jump 1

- [Calvin City](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Calvin_City): In DC Comics, home to the Golden Age (first) Atom: [Al Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(Al_Pratt)).

### Episode 1x12

#### Time Jump 2

- [Paradise Island](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Paradise_Island): In DC Comics, it is also called Themyscira  and is the home of the Amazons. Wonder Woman is a princess of here.
- Starling City 2007: The name of Oliver Queen's home before Palmer Technologies rebranded it to "Star City" in 2015 (Ray first mentioned his desire to change it in *Arrow*, "[The Calm](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/The_Calm)", and it was officially rebranded in "[Green Arrow](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Arrow)"). Since the Legends visit it in 2007 before this rebranding, it's good to see that somebody on the production is paying attention.

#### Time Jump 3

- Star City 2014: Unfortunately production staff wasn't paying attention here, as the rebranding to Star City didn't take place until 2015 after Ray Palmer's supposed death, so this entry (and the one in the next time jump) should read "Starling City". It's possible that the Legends have changed the timeline to the point where the city was rebranded a year earlier, but that seems unlikely given that the goal of this time jump was to save Ray Palmer, who is still a public figure and has not been presumed dead yet.

### Episode 1x16

#### Time Jump 11

- [Cuzco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusco) 1941: In *Just Imagine: Wonder Woman* (a series in which Stan Lee reimagined the origins of DC heroes), [Maria Mendoza](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Maria_Mendoza_(Just_Imagine)) became Wonder Woman during an archeological excavation at Cuzco. Additionally, the year listed is 1941, which is the year that Wonder Woman (as Diana Prince) first appeared in DC Comics.

---

## Strange Choices

There are a few time jump locations that don't look like easter eggs, but I can't figure out why they were chosen.

### Episode 1x14

#### Time Jump 1

- Maya City: There doesn't seem to have been a singular city called "Maya City", but there certainly were plenty of [cities in the Mayan Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_city).

---

## Small Locations

There were a number of locations that seemed to be uncharacteristically small compared to most other cities that have appeared. They might be a reference to something I don’t know about, or they are just in-jokes among the production team to their birth places or something. The majority of them appear to be US cities.

### Episode 1x01

#### Time Jump 3

- Vestal: This location also appears in Episodes 1x10 and 1x16 (more than any other location in this section), which makes me wonder if this is a reference that I don't know. The only place I can find with this name is the small real-world town of [Vestal, NY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestal,_New_York).

#### Time Jump 4

- Williamston: Either [Williamston, NC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williamston,_North_Carolina) or [Williamston, MI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williamston,_Michigan).

#### Time Jump 6

- Peach Tree City: Possibly a misspelling of [Peachtree City, GA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peachtree_City,_Georgia).

### Episode 1x02

#### Time Jump 1

- Port Washington: Either [Port Washington, NY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_Washington,_New_York) or [Port Washington, WI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_Washington,_Wisconsin)

### Episode 1x08

#### Time Jump 1

- West Lafayette: Likely [West Lafayette, IN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Lafayette,_Indiana).

### Episode 1x09

#### Time Jump 2

- Riverside: Likely [Riverside, CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riverside,_California)
- Perris: Likely [Perris, CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perris,_California).
- Binghamton: Likely [Binghamton, NY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binghamton,_New_York).

### Episode 1x13

#### Time Jump 2

- West Hills: Probably one of [several US cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Hills) with the name.
- Los Alamos: Likely [Los Alamos, CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Alamos,_California).

### Episode 1x14

#### Time Jump 1

- Sanam: The only places I could find with this name are [a few villages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanam) in the Middle East and Africa.

### Episode 1x16

#### Time Jump 3

- Shreveport: Likely [Shreveport, LA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shreveport,_Louisiana).